# Slow down in mongodb when performing bulk insert of more than 5 million documents in batch of 1000

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

I'm trying to read and process documents from a collection containing 14 million documents with an average size of 0.7Kb. After adding a new field, I'm performing bulk insert into a different empty collection. The batch size is 1000.

The data processing python pymongo jobs, two in parallel are running on a t2.medium ec2 instance.

```
 while skip < total_count:

            # Query MongoDB to get a batch of records within the date range
            batch_records = collection.find({
                    'groupIds' : 2,
                    "createdOn": { '$gte': start_date, '$lte': end_date}}).skip(skip).limit(batch_size)
```

The mongo server is running in docker on an m4.xlarge ec2 instance.

There is a terrible slowdown in processing after 5 million records. It takes abt 4 hours to process 5M and then could process only about a million in the next 3 hours.

During this slowdown, the CPU utlization on mongo drops to 30% on each core, while RAN utilized is stable at 50%.

I tried setting wired tiger cache to 80% of RAM, still the performance is the same.
Currently about 12GB of RAM is being used and 3GB is available.

There are no additional indexes on new collection except for the default one.

What else can be done to improve performance here ?

Comment: _"After adding a new field, ..."_  What is this new field?  How is it determined? I'm wondering if an aggregation pipeline on the original collection that ends with [`"$merge"`](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/merge/) could be used.  If so, the MongoDB server could do the entire transformation and create the new collection.

Comment: Please provide more context around the problem. Sample document which is inserted would be helpful as well.